# How to query by type and date?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I cant get user recipe Ids to list

I try to query by whereEqualTo and orderBy but on compile firebase suggested me to create indexing, so I did that but it dont give me any results.

```
for (String mealType : dishTypeList){

     userCollectionReference.document(userId).collection("favourites")
            .whereEqualTo("mealType", mealType)
            .orderBy("dateWhenSetFavourite", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

            List<String> favouriteRecipeIds = new ArrayList<>();

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){

                favouriteRecipeIds.add(document.toObject(FavouriteRecipeModel.class).getRecipeId());
                Log.d(TAG, "LIST LIST: " + favouriteRecipeIds);

            }

            myFirebaseCallBack.onSuccessCallback(favouriteRecipeIds);

        }
    });
}
```

I want to get recipeId whereEqualTo by mealType and ordered by dateWhenSetToFavourites

This is my database:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `dishTypeList` contains the same dish types that are used in the database? If yes, your code looks fine to me. If all your objects in the database contain the recipe id than the following code should work:

```
favouriteRecipeIds.add(document.toObject(FavouriteRecipeModel.class).getRecipeId());
```

Otherwise, a more simpler way of getting the document id would be:

```
favouriteRecipeIds.add(document.getId());
```

Beside that, everytime you are getting as a result a `Task` object, check to see if it is successful:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    //Your logic
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());
}
```

And also use the else part of the statement to check for an error message.

Comment: Thank you my mistake was very silly, it works now just fine.